# Why can't i delete [] tmp after using tmp to push back new element to another original array

Tags: c++, oop, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

I am in my 1st year in CS ,in the middle of an OOP course.We have started learning about dynamically allocated arrays in C++. And we are now solving a lot of problems, where we have to push back an object into an already dynamically allocated array of classes.

```
void functionInAClass(ClassName newObject){
    ClassName *tmp = new ClassName [this->size+1];

    for(int i = 0; i < this->size; i++){
        tmp[i] = this->arr[i];
    }
    tmp [this->size++] = newObject;

    delete [] this->arr;
    this->arr = tmp;
}
```

->>> delete [] tmp // why is it that if i add this line, my code doesnt run, our proffesors haven't really explained anything, can't i delete [] tmp since i don't need it anymore,or if i do need it,why?
and why does it work if i put in tmp = nullptr;
this is what i get:

```
***Error***
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: You shouldn't delete `tmp` because `tmp` and `this->arr` are pointing to the same thing, and you need `this->arr`

Comment: When you do `this->arr = tmp;` you tell `arr` to point to the data that `tmp` does.  If you then do `delete [] tmp` after that, what memory does `arr` now point to?

Comment: Just because this is the line where the program crashes or reports an error doesn't mean this is where the problem is. C++ does not work this way. The problem can be anywhere in your code, but after the bug occurs the program keeps running for a little bit before it finally crashes here. This is why stackoverflow.com's [help] requires you to show a [mre] that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, then compile, run, and reproduce your problem. See [ask] for more information. Until you do that, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to figure out your problem.

Comment: You have performed ownership transfer from `tmp` to `this->arr` (`delete [] this->arr;` is kind of replacement of deleting `tmp`), so why you think delete of `tmp` is needed here?

Comment: University computer science C++ courses using `new` and `delete` should be reserved for the very advanced courses in the C++ series.  They need to [Stop Teaching C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) as C++.  I've not needed `new` or `delete` in the last 12 years of the 33 years I've been doing C++.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)

Answer (score 1):

You allocated dynamically an array

```
ClassName *tmp = new ClassName [this->size+1];
```

then why are you going to delete it?

```
delete [] tmp;
```

What is the sense of the function in this case?

The class has data member `arr`. You need to reallocate the array pointed to by the pointer arr and to add one more element in the newly allocated array.

So you allocate a new array with the number of elements greater by one than the number of the current dynamically allocated array pointed to by the data member arr.

```
ClassName *tmp = new ClassName [this->size+1];
```

copy existent element in the new allocated array

```
for(int i = 0; i < this->size; i++){
    tmp[i] = this->arr[i];
}
```

and add the new element

```
tmp [this->size++] = newObject;
```

Now the previously allocated array is not needed any more and can be deleted.

```
delete [] this->arr;
```

and the data member arr is reassigned with the address of the new allocated array

```
this->arr = tmp;
```

If you will delete the new allocated array like

```
delete [] tmp;
```

then the pointer arr will be invalid. So there is no any sense to allocate a new array and at once to delete it.

I think the reason of misunderstanding is that you think that this statement

```
delete [] tmp;
```

deletes the pointer tmp itself.

But actually this statement does not delete the pointer tmp. It deletes the dynamically allocated memory pointed to by the pointer tmp.